# I can actually install a few apps without provisioning

Tags: iphone, ios, installation, device, provisioning

Yesterday I was playing with the three20 library. I hit the command+enter to build and run the app on my simulator, to my surprise it installed the app on my device iPod Touch 4th Gen. I really dont know how that happened, I tried doing it with few of my other project and unfortunately it did not work.

Today, I downloaded the quick contacts sample code from Apple's developer site and the same thing happened, I could install the app on my device without any provisioning. I see that for the above two projects (three20 and quick contacts) my device is listed in the active executables.

But for other projects my device isn't listed. I tried running the above two apps on other devices which failed with a message - "No provisioned iOS device found". My device isn't jailbroken, its a brand new one I bought a few days ago.

Am I missing something, because being able to install apps without going thru Apple's portal is a huge bonus and I would like to achieve the same functionality for my other apps too.

I tried attaching screenshots, but looks like I atleast need 10 points to do so and I'm new here. Sorry.

Comment: +1. There you go! Aren't we nice? Or perhaps we're just dying to see this.

Comment: That's interesting and all, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: @BoltClock: My question is how am I able to install apps without provisioning? And why can't I do it for other devices? And why can't I do it for my other apps?

Let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: update: looks like I can install almost any app onto the device without provisioning. Not possible with other devices I have. Can somebody enlighten me how this is possible?

Comment: What versión of xcode are you using? Newer versions take care of provisioning if no profile is selected for you app and device.

Comment: Zebs, I'm using XCode 3.2.5, probably as you and Jessedc mention XCode might be taking care of provisioning, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the XCode Organizer; As of a few versions ago it now manages a 'Team Provisioning Profile' that works off any bundle identifier and any of your devices if they've been added to your developer account. This is not a special provisioning profile, just an automatic one it sets up for you if you tell it your iTunes Connect details.

WIth this, anything you build and run should be able to use that provisioning profile to run code on your devices.

Comment: Hey Jessedc, thanks for the answer. I did not know it was there until you pointed out. And yes, I think this is what that lets me install apps without creating specific provisioning profile for each one.

So, from now is it just enough if we have the team provision file to install apps to all our listed devices? Is it the expected behavior what Apple intended?